# Java JUnit for xml file

Tags: xml, junit, transformation

I have to write a JUnit test.

I am generating xml file and filling it with some data.
My example:

```
try {

    DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

    // root elements
    Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();

    Element rootElement = doc.createElement("competition");
    doc.appendChild(rootElement);

    for(int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++){

    // singleuser elements
    Element singleuser = doc.createElement("singlerow");
    rootElement.appendChild(singleuser);

    // participant elements
    Element participant = doc.createElement("participant");
    participant.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(dataList.get(i).getData().getParticipantScores()));
    singleuser.appendChild(participant);

    // score elements
    Element score = doc.createElement("score");
    score.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(dataList.get(i).getData().getFinalScore().toString()));
    singleuser.appendChild(score);

    // score elements
    Element place = doc.createElement("place");
    place.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(dataList.get(i).getData().getPlace()));
    singleuser.appendChild(place);
    }

    // write the content into xml file
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("testXml.xml"));

    transformer.transform(source, result);
    System.out.println("File saved!");

} catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
    pce.printStackTrace();
} catch (TransformerException tfe) {
    tfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

So this code part generates my .xml file.. and eveyrthing is ok with that.

But about JUnit test for this part..

What can I test here?
Any examples ?

So far what I found googling is just simple string comparing tests.

Any tip would be very helpful.

I can use only pure java 8 + JUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You can test anything and everything. The easiest approach is test first development: write a test that expects something; e.g that the output file is well-formed. Then write the minimum amount of code to make that pass.

Then write a test that expects the name competition for the root element. Add the minimum amount of code to make that test pass.

Then write a test for the `singlerow` element, and so on. Iterate until done.

One test per expected element is probably adequate here.

See [Testing XML](https://www.ibiblio.org/xml/slides/sd2006west/testingxml/)